# How to run GNUstep .app files?

Tags: application, gnustep

I found Debian contains many .app files under the gnustep package and its dependencies. I tried installing them, but running apps from the command line, such as "terminal.app" doesn't seem to work, as these don't seem to be in the path. What is the proper way to launch .app programs in Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check the [user FAQ for gnustep](http://wiki.gnustep.org/index.php/User_FAQ).

To run an app you need the `openapp` program:

```
openapp Terminal
```

will run `Terminal.app`.

You can also specify an absolute or relative path for it, and add or leave out the `.app` suffix.